# cfthread issue in lucee

Tags: multithreading, lucee

I encounter a problem that is not very discussed on the internet:

I have an application that run under Railo server. The cfthread tag worked very well on Railo.

Once I migrate my application to Lucee server, the cfthread doesn't work, and I get this message error: "thread scope cannot be modified from outside the owner thread", when I tried to affect a variable from inside the thread ()

The same code worked under Railo.

Can anyone has any idea about this issue? I tried to change the release, but It also doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From the error message, I would think it is a coding issue which was exploiting a bug in Railo, which version of Lucee are you running?

Comment: Hi andrewwdixon, I have the release 5.2.5.20

Comment: Can you post an example of the code?

Comment: Looks like there is a bug report for it in the Lucee JIRA: https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1389

Comment: It appears to suggest that any version before and include 5.1.3.18 works ok and after this version it is broken. You can download version 5.1.3.18 or before from the downloads site: http://download.lucee.org/

Comment: I've just been contacted by Patrick, and Lucee Product Manager @i-am-sigmund to say he on to it.

Comment: thnaks andrewdixon. I downgrade to the release 5.1.3.18 and it works!!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by a bug in Lucee that was introduced after version 5.1.3.18. It has been fixed for an upcoming release, see bug report:

https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-1389